# How can I take a live desktop website and start transforming it into a mobile website?

Tags: moovweb

I would like to take a standard desktop site that isn't my own [slashdot.org](http://slashdot.org) and transform it into a mobile friendly site. How can I do this using Moovweb?

Comment: This sounds unethical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of documentation on [the Moovweb site](http://console.moovweb.com) - the [building a mobile site tutorials](https://console.moovweb.com/learn/training/building_a_site/index) are probably the most useful for what you're asking.

If you need to get started from the very beginning (as in - you haven't even downloaded it), [there's a getting started guide also](https://console.moovweb.com/learn/training/getting_started/index).